# Adding angular component input data from inside subscribe

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material, rxjs-observables

I have component1.ts:

```
  export class Component1 implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
    public inputData1: any[] = [];
    public inputData2: any[] = [];
    public inputData3: any[] = [];
    private sub: Subscription;

    ngOnInit() {
       this.sub= this.service.dataObservable.subscribe((val: any) => {
       try {
          this.inputData1 = some logic to filter input data1 from val. <--- Here this.inputdata1/2/3 says undefined after assignment.
          this.inputData2 = some logic to filter input data2 from val.
          this.inputData3 = some logic to filter input data3 from val. 
       }
       catch (ex) {
    
       }
    }
```

component.html

```
<mat-card class="tab-card">
   <app-component2 [inputData1]='inputData1' [inputData2]='inputData2' [inputData3]='inputData3' > 
   </app-component2>
</mat-card>
```

component2.ts

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit {

  inputData1Columns: string[] = ['col1', 'col2'];
  @Input() inputData1: any[] = [];
  inputDataSource1 = new MatTableDataSource(this.inputData1);

  inputData2Columns: string[] = ['col1', 'col2'];
  @Input() inputData2: any[] = [];
  inputDataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource(this.inputData2);

  inputData3Columns: string[] = ['col1', 'col2'];
  @Input() inputData3: any[] = [];
  inputDataSource3 = new MatTableDataSource(this.inputData3);

  constructor() {}

}
```

For some reason when the subscription is triggered and the inputdata1,2,3 are not assigned. When i put a breakpoint, it says inputdata1 is undefined. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your inputdata1,2,3 undefined in your child component or in your subscription?

Comment: @Marek W In my subscription it is undefined, it should also be undefined in child component

Comment: Basically the data is not going into child component

Comment: @user9969157 how do you know that the data is not being passed to the child component? Are you setting inputData1/2/3 inside the ngOnInit inside component2.ts as well or only in the class definition?